# Counting problem - number of ways to select books

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The question is:

> There are $10$ copies of one book and one copy each of $10$ other books.
>   In how many ways can we select $10$ books?

The answer is $2^{10}$ but I don't understand why. Maybe there is some sort of assumption in the way to choose books that the question doesn't make clear, but I thought it the answer would just be:

> There are $20$ books total, and I want to choose 10 of them, so the
>   answer is $20 \times 19 \times 18 \times 17 \times 16 \times 15 \times 14 \times 13 \times 12 \times 11$

Comment: It seems to me that order does not matter in this problem and there are repeats so your method won't work. You can't distinguish between the copies of the first book, so you don't really have 20 books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reasoning is as follows: there are $2^{10}$ ways to pick any number between $0$ and $10$ of the unique books (for each of the books, you either bring it, or you don't; that's ten choices with two options in each choice). Then you pick enough of the book there are many copies of to get to ten books in total. This last step can be done in exactly one way.

What you've not accounted for are two things: first, that the *order* in which you pick your ten books shouldn't matter (only which books you end up with in the end). It matters according to your calculation. Second, exactly what subset of the identical books we pick should not matter, but it does in your calculation. This is why you get a much higher number.